# Proof about the dimension space spanned by the sum of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be squared matrices of dimension $n$ with $rank(A)=m$ ($0<m<n$); $rank(B)=n-m$ and $rank(A+B)=n$.

I would like to prove that $R^n$ is direct sum of ${\cal R}(A)$ (the space spanned by the columns of $A$) and ${\cal R}(B)$.

Comment: It is certainly generated by the columns of $A+B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $x_1,...,x_n$ are the columns of $A$ and $y_1,...,y_n$ are the columns of $B$.

From the rank of $A+B$ we get that $(x_1+y_1),...,(x_n+y_n)$ generate the space. 
Therefore $x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_n$ can generate the space. So $R(A)+R(B)=R^n$

So, the question is whether $R(A)\cap R(B)\neq0$

We are given that $\dim(R(A))=k$ and $\dim(R(B))=n-k$.

If $\dim(R(A)\cap R(B))=m>0$ then

\begin{align}\dim(R(A)+R(B))&=\dim(R(A))+\dim(R(B))-\dim(R(A)\cap R(B))\\
&=k+(n-k)-m\\&=n-m\\&<n\end{align}

Therefore $m=0$.